# Hiding particular field in parameter combo box using ArcObjects and C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net

I am currently fetching the all fields/attributes of feature class and display in Combo box parameter using below code:

```c#
paramEdit = new GPParameterClass();
paramEdit.DataType = new DEFeatureClassType() as IGPDataType;
paramEdit.Value = new DEFeatureClass() as IGPValue;
paramEdit.Direction = esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionInput;
paramEdit.DisplayName = "Feature Class 1";
paramEdit.DisplayOrder = inputTable1Index;
paramEdit.Enabled = true;
paramEdit.Name = "in_line_featureclass1";
paramEdit.ParameterType = esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeRequired;
paramEdit.Domain = lineFeatureClassDomain as IGPDomain;
paramArray.Add(paramEdit);

paramEdit = new GPParameterClass();
paramEdit.DataType = (IGPDataType)new FieldType();
paramEdit.Value = (IGPValue)new Field();                
paramEdit.Direction = esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionInput;
paramEdit.DisplayName = "Select attributes from Feature Class 1";
paramEdit.DisplayOrder = inputDynamicList1Index;
paramEdit.Enabled = true;
paramEdit.Name = "in_line_featureclass1_attrib";
paramEdit.ParameterType = esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeOptional;
paramEdit.AddDependency("in_line_featureclass1");
IGPFeatureSchema outputSchema = new GPFeatureSchemaClass();
IGPSchema schema = (IGPSchema)outputSchema;                
schema.CloneDependency = true;
paramEdit.Schema = outputSchema as IGPSchema;
paramArray.Add(paramEdit);
```

I want to hide some fields which display in this combo box parameter.

Is it possible to hide the fields or display selected fields from feature class ?

[image]

As shown in above image when I selecting feature class it display the fields of that feature class in combo box but I want to hide some fields in that combo box so how can I do this?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're trying to do here.. you talk about a combo box but are showing code with gp parameter object.

Comment: @Michael Stimson I have updated the question. Using the code I have written above it display output as shown in image I attached.

Comment: Oh, it's not a Windows form combo box, it's a geoprocessor dialog box. That makes the question clearer but unfortunately I can't help, I've not used that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this if we want to hide the field according to particular data types then we need to set domain for this.
In my case I don't want to display a SHAPE field i.e. Geometry fields in combo box parameter, so I have set the domain like below:

```
IGPFieldDomain fieldDomain = new GPFieldDomainClass();
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeInteger);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeSmallInteger);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeSingle);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeString);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDate);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGlobalID);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeGUID);
fieldDomain.AddType(esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeOID);
```

i.e. I have set domain for all fields except geometry so this will not display geometry type fields in combo box.

and set this domain to parameter like:

```
paramEdit.Domain = fieldDomain as IGPDomain;
```